# How can I configure BIND that it FORWARDS lookups to an internet dns

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, bind, dns-zone

I would like to configure BIND that I have a few "local" zones with manual entries and all other lookups should be forwarded to an external internet dns.
How can I do that?

Maybe I'm absolutely wrong, but I haven't got a lot of experience with it.

Thanks in advance
Lars

Comment: If you meant an internet proxy, my answer won't apply, but otherwise the solution is to learn a bit about BIND so you can configure it as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply configure your server as you said it. Make your local zones where you are "master", and setup DNS forwarders in the `forwarders {}` block (typically in `named.conf` or `named.conf.options` on debian for instance).

The server will be authoritative over the local zones but it will defer all other lookups to internet nameservers you specify in the forwarders block.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I found my mistake. I wrote forwarders { ip_address }; and not forwarders { ip_address; }; (missing semicolon)

Comment: Alright :) Please mark the answer as the correct one if it solved your issue, I can edit the question and answer a bit to highlight the forwarders problem (or you can maybe edit the question yourself depending on your reputation here)